# Perl hash value without key name

Tags: perl, hash

Is it possible in Perl to access a value of a hash, if it has just one key, without using key value?

Let's say, `%h` has just `'key_name' => 'value'`.

Can I access the `'value'` only via `$h->{key_name}`?

Or, is possible to access this `'value'` without key name?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [values](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) builtin function for hashes will return a list of all the hash values.  You can use this to get or set any values with aliasing list constructs such as `foreach`, `map`, and `grep`:

```
for my $value (values %hash) {
    say $value;  # prints the value
    $value++;    # adds one to the value
}
```

Or you can store the values in an array:

```
my @vals = values %hash;
```

The order of the returned values is effectively random, but it will be the same order as the corresponding `keys` function.

Hashes themselves are lists, so you can access any odd element of the hash in list context to get at the value, but this method is less efficient since the whole hash needs to be taken apart to form the list, not just the values.

The techniques above work with hashes of any size.  If you only have one key / value pair:

```
my %hash = qw(foo bar);
```

Then they reduce to:

```
{my ($x) = values %hash;    say $x} # bar
{my (undef, $x) = %hash;    say $x} # bar
{my $x = (values %hash)[0]; say $x} # bar
{my $x = (%hash)[1];        say $x} # bar
```

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this. For example:

```
my %h=("key_name"=>"value"); print values(%h)
```

or

```
my %h=("key_name"=>"value"); print( (%h)[1])
```

But in my opinion that doesn't look pretty...

Answer (score -2):

You've got two options here - you can either optimize for space, or optimize for time.  If you need to get the key from that value and you don't care about how long it takes, you can iterate over each entry in the associative array:

```
while(($key, $value) = each(%h))
{
    if($value eq 'value')
    {
        return $key;
    }
}
```

But if you don't mind having two copies, the most time-efficient solution is to hold a backwards and forwards associative array -- that is: `%h_by_name` and `%h_by_value`.

In this case, if you have multiple keys with the same value, your `%h_by_value` should contain an array.  That is if:

```
%h_by_name = (
    "a" => "1",
    "b" => "1",
    "c" => "1",
    "d" => 2"
);
```

Then you would want to construct your `%h_by_value` such that it was:

```
%h_by_value = (
    "1" => [ "a", "b", "c" ],
    "2" => [ "d" ]
);
```

Comment: While your second suggestion works in this instance (only one key=value pair).  Only keys are guaranteed unique and so you could lose pairs with matching values using this method

Comment: @SkryneSaver: yes, obviously if you have the same value for multiple unique keys then you would need to add a level of indirection.  Still significantly faster than looping over the entire hash looking at their values.